# Julia: boolean comparisons with arrays

Tags: julia

I have a simple question about boolean comparisons in Julia. How do I translate the following Matlab code to Julia?

Matlab:

```
% create parameters
o = -3;
mat = [65 -4; 65 -3; 65 -2]

% determine which rows of matrix have column 2 less than o AND column 1 equal to 65.
result = (o < mat(:,2) & mat(:,1) == 65)
```

I've tried the following in Julia:

```
# create parameters
o = -3
mat = zeros(3,2)
mat[:,1] = 65
mat[1,2] = -4
mat[2,2] = -3
mat[3,2] = -2
mat

# attempt to create desired result
o .< mat[:,2]                                # this part works
mat[:,1] .== 65                              # this part works
test = (o .< mat[:,2] && mat[:,1] .== 65)    # doesn't work
test = (o .< mat[:,2] .& mat[:,1] .== 65)    # doesn't work
test = (o .< mat[:,2] & mat[:,1] .== 65)     # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a matter of operator precedence.  `&` has a higher precedence in Julia than it does in Matlab.  Just shift around your parentheses:

```
test = (o .< mat[:,2]) .& (mat[:,1] .== 65)
```

See [Noteworthy differences from Matlab](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/#Noteworthy-differences-from-MATLAB-1) in the manual for more details (and it's worth reading through the other differences, too).

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can use the same array creation syntax in Julia:

```
julia> mat = [65 -4; 65 -3; 65 -2]
3x2 Array{Int64,2}:
65  -4
65  -3
65  -2
```

You can also use `find` to get a list of the resulting indices:

```
o = -3
test = (o .< mat[:,2]) & (mat[:,1] .== 65)

julia> find(test)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
3
```